# AC circuit analysis homework, finding voltages and currents

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, homework

[image: The question]

[image: The circuit]

I've been trying this question for a while. I'm not sure where to start. I tried redrawing the circuit differently but that did not help much.

Please ignore the fact that my drawing is not neat, it was just a rough one, I was checking if it would help before actually doing it neatly.

[image]

Comment: Use KCL and KVL then solve.

Comment: Thanks, but to find I1, I would first need to find the total impedance right? I don't know how to simplify this further :/

Comment: There are 2 loops and 3 nodes in this schematic. So 5 equations. Just write these. with 5 currents unknown.

Comment: 4 nodes, isn't it?

Comment: 2 loops for KVL. 3 nodes for KCL. Confirmed. See answer. I did not simplify anything. Let it as it is.

Comment: 5 nodes, move H up

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75  Don't understand for 5 nodes? The lower node is obvious i3+i4=i1 (combination of my equations 3, 4, 5), so don't need.  Where is the 5th node needed for writing a new useful equation?

Comment: BH are same node so I was replying to @Crab00189, so there are 5 node KCL equations and 3 loop KVL' s but only 5 unknown currents, so pick any 5 equations out of 8.

Comment: Sorry @TonyStewartEE75 . You are right. I have a bad habit of not "including" current sources in loops. So, I counted (for necessary equations), 2 loops and 3 nodes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know what techniques you are using. But what I see quickly transforms into this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWtAvj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I converted the Thevenin source plus resistance on the left side into a Norton equivalent and labeled the nodes. Both of the current sources are in phase with each other, so that simplifies the process below.

The KCL is easy:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{V_x}{4}+\frac{V_x}{-j\,2} &= 5 + 5 + \frac{V_y}{-j\,2}
\\\\
\frac{V_y}{-j\,2}+\frac{V_y}{-j\,2}+\frac{V_y}{j\,10}&=\frac{V_x}{-j\,2}+\frac{V_z}{j\,10}
\\\\
\frac{V_z}{8}+\frac{V_z}{j\,10}+5&=\frac{V_y}{j\,10}
\end{align*}$$

From this, it solves out as: \$V_x=\frac1{17}\left(360-j\,240\right)\$, \$V_y=\frac1{17}\left(240-j\,80\right)\$, and \$V_z=\frac1{17}\left(-360-j\,480\right)\$.

That's also the same as: \$V_x\approx 25.451 \;\angle {-}33.69^\circ\$, \$V_y\approx 14.881 \;\angle {-}18.435^\circ\$, and \$V_z\approx 35.294 \;\angle {-}126.87^\circ\$. Note that these are RMS values!!

You can work out the rest of the details, I suspect. Including the time-domain equations if you need them. (Don't forget to convert from RMS to peak values, if you attempt that.)

A short run from LTspice (using your voltage source and not my Norton equivalent) shows the following results:

[image]

Which is close enough to satisfy me that I didn't badly mess up the Thevenin to Norton or the following KCL.

Comment: Saying "nice, +1" would be a bit redundant at this point, but I'll just add that the measurements would more precise with an `.ac list {f}`.

Comment: Thanks jonk! Appreciate it!

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I honestly don't know how to apply that in this case. I'd like to learn more about what you mean, too.

Comment: @jonk You performed a `.TRAN` analysis and then you used `Ctrl+LClick` on the waveform's label, which gave you the three shown measurements, but those will be an RMS performed on a waveform that's made of discrete points; it may suffer from timestep, compression, etc. With an `.AC` analysis at one frequency, you get a precise measurement of magnitude and phase, an intrinsic result, not calculated based on a measurement (I hope I manage to get some message across, I can't find all the good words now). Nothing new, just `.AC` insteaad of `.TRAN` (so nothing you didn't know, already :-) ).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Yeah. Well, I tried what I thought you were hand-waving at and didn't get useful results. But I also didn't post up my schematic, either. So perhaps it is a difference in what you may visualize I have here vs what I really do have here. (I applied it to the voltage source. But I've two AC sources here. If you want, I could post it up and then you could point to the modifications I'd need to apply. I am honestly short on ideas about LTspice use here. My fault, not yours, of course.

Comment: Hey @jonk I checked your CircuitLab schematic but the impedances have not been defined. and there is no option either. we can online input inductance for inductor and capacitance for capacitor... here's a snap https://pasteboard.co/R0xREDGxaekz.png. I then tried making the circuit in LTspice, but that too requires me to know the inductance and capacitance instead of allowing me to just input the impedance.. so Im curious how you did it

Comment: @Crab00189 It's not hard. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN8ES.png).

Comment: @jonk My apologies, I didn't mean to hand-wave, nothing condescending intended. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKu99.png) is what I meant: the results come out as magnitude and phase, straight up, with more precision given by `.opt numdgt>6 measdgt=<...>` (I used peak values because of the way the problem is stated in the OP).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen That is one step beyond my knowledge. I never tried two AC sources before!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Good job, @jonk.

Applying directly KVL and KCL.

[image]

Calculated directly currents. Voltages are obvious. (unless error).

Adapted for RMS values. Sources (phase=0).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this!!

Comment: is V1-4= voltage across 4 ohm resistor?

Comment: V1-4? Where?  I did not use any voltage except the voltage source v(t)=V1. For the voltages, calculate only i*Z. So Voltage across 4 Ohm is = i1*4. The voltage across the inductor is = i5*j10. Be careful about the direction of polarity of the voltage vs current.

Comment: Ohh thanks! What's Iinj tho?

Comment: Iinj is i(t), source current "injected" in the circuit.

Comment: oh thank you!!!